# константное значение n, m

Tags: c++, массивы

Пытаюсь получить транспонированную матрицу, но выдает ошибку
Выражение должно иметь константное значение n, m;
Не могу понять что не так, пример с сайта брал говорят рабочий

Если есть реализация проще, например с одним циклом, буду рад.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n, m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int M[n][m]; 
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
         for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
               cin >> M[i][j];  
         }
    }
    int M1[m][n];

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
         for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
               M1[i][j]=M[j][i];
         }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
         for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
             cout<<M1[i][j]<<" ";
         }
         cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Говорят рабочий"? Врут.

Comment: @AnT Врут по любому, потому что не проверен на visual studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такие фокусы

```
int n, m;
cin>>n>>m;
int M[n][m];
```

**стандартом** запрещены (работает в качестве расширения GCC). Размеры массивов должны быть определены во время компиляции.

Вам стоит воспользоваться векторами, например

```
vector<vector<int>> M(n,vector<int>(m));
```

или выделять память динамически типа

```
int **M = new int*[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) M[i] = new int[m];
```

а потом не забывать ее освобождать...

Comment: да спасибо, сделал с помощью вектора 

int n, m;
cin>>n>>m;
`vector<vector<int>> M(n,vector<int>(m));`

и там внизу еще
`vector<vector<int>> M1(m, vector<int>(n));`

Конечно код какой то сложный не могли блин с одним циклом сделать или это не возможно)

Comment: Ну, одним циклом - это, конечно, можно - но будет выглядеть очень запутанно, а по времени - все равно то же самое :) Нет смысла извращаться.

Comment: а если 2 цикла, просто сейчас их 6 это писец и поробуй понять что происходит там, с ходу не поймешь нужно думать каждый раз как видешь код, а вот что бы как 2+2 понять нефига.

Comment: Первые два - ввод данных, вторые - получение транспонированной матрицы, третьи - вывод транспонированной матрицы...Можно в принципе объединить первые два и записывать сразу транспонированную матрицу... Но если объединить с третьими - то на экране получится каша :)

Comment: тоже верно, буду экспериментировать, хотя все равно считаю чисто математически можно без циклов, достаточно 1 цикла.

Comment: У меня тут еще одна проблема появилась, если код такой `double sum[l], sr[l];` как его в вектор запихать, пробовал так не получается `vector<vector<double>> sum(l), sr(l);` мне пишет перегрузка и отсутствует оператор равно тут `sum[i]=0;` это другой код но тоже с матрицей дело )

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```
//для неких констанных значений
// например   const int n = 5, m = 6;
int M[n][m],  //  ваша матрица
      Mt[m][n] ; // для транспонации   
std::valarray<int> 
v(M[0], n * m),     // инициализирован из М
// транспонированная  
   vs(v[std::gslice(0, {m, n}, {1, m})]); 
// копирование в массив
std::copy_n(&vs[0], n * m, Mt[0] );
```

Comment: Чет не получается запустить ошибок куча, можно с функцией
`using namespace std;` и вектором

Comment: #include <algorithm>
#include <valarray>       подключать нужно соответствующие файлы

Comment: Ошибка (активно) E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "std::valarray<_Ty>::valarray [с _Ty=int]", соответствующие списку аргументов

Comment: нет там никакой ошибки.  Вы что то  то упускаете